# angularjs - how to read the src attribute of an iframe element as it changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, iframe

I'm trying to understand how to read the src attribute of an iframe as the user navigates the iframe from the parent page that contains the iframe.  Is this possible?

So, lets say I set the iframe src attribute intitally to

"http://www.example.com"

Then the user navigates to

"http://www.example.com/anotherpage.html"

**How can I know when that change is made and to what new src?**

Any help appreciated,

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can implement by using custom directive.

```
  <iframe ng-src="{{iframelink}}" iframeurlload></iframe>
```

Custom directive

```
app.directive('iframeurlload', function($state) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('load', function() {
                    var url =angular.element(document.querySelector('iframe')).contents()[0].URL;
                    if (url.includes("anotherpage")){
                        // Do anything what you want
                    }
                });

            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onLoad event,  so in your case provide a handler:

```
 <iframe src="http://www.example.com" onLoad="iFrameSourceChanged(this);"></iframe>

var originalUrl = "http://www.example.com";
function iFrameSourceChanged(iframe)
{
     if(iframe.src != originalUrl)
      {
         // it changed to a different source
      }
}
```

The iFrameSourceChanged function will be called whenever the source of the iframe changes